# Separate arguments in c preprocessor macro

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Suppose we have code like this:

```
#define SOME_MACRO(arg)    /*macro body*/

int main()
{
      SOME_MACRO(a = 1);
}
```

Is it possible to separate tokens passed in one argument in c preprocessor?

What I mean is it possible to get 'a', '=', '1' in macro body as separate tokens?

If there are no tricks to do it in general way may be it is possible in this particular case with 'a = 1' as argument to get 'a' as a separate token so that I can use it it 'macro body'?

Comment: Could it be `SOME_MACRO("a =b");`?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: No. I'm particularly interested in case SOME_MACRO(a = b).

Comment: I want have some macro with possible usage like: MACRO(a = 1, b = 3, c = 4, ...). And I wan to get separate tokens 'a', 'b', 'c' in its body

Comment: That looks like you are trying to get too fancy with macros (and does not answer the question by @Lundin). Concentrate on readable and debuggable code. Such macro-magic can complicate debugging until no use.

Comment: Please clearly explain what you want to accomplish ? if you assign a=b always a's value will be "b". What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I want to write some wrapper around enum declaration and get enum constant names so that I can use them in macro body

Comment: @SeleznevAnton: You should *ask a question* about what you want to do. Not bury your intent at the bottom of a long comment thread.

Comment: There are several ways to write macros to create some kind of introspection for enums. There are some libraries to solve this problem and I know about them so I don't ask about underlying problem. At the moment I'm particularly interested in some abstract question about c preprocessor that can help me do it my way. That's why I don't ask about real problem that I want to solve.

Comment: @SeleznevAnton: The preprocessor does not offer any mechanism to split an argument into separate tokens. You (or someone else) might be able to come up with a way to accomplish a specific task (like ignore `= b` if `b` is known to be a numeric literal), but in order to do that, you (they) would need to be clear about the specific task. That's my suggestion, fwiw.

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't possible unless the macro argument list is comma-separated. You would have to do

```
SOME_MACRO(a, =, b);
```

or otherwise `a = b` ends up as a single pre-processor token.

Comment: could you explain how _,=_ can fit in a macro?

Comment: `a=b` is three preprocessor tokens unless you stringify it. But that doesn't give you any obvious way to separate them into separate tokens.